# Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo getting the Recovery Model of the SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Anyone have an good references with examples of how I can check the SQL Server Recovery Model from C#? I have been unable to find an good examples.

Edit

Here is what I have and it seems to be working my question is there a better way to do this

```
public void GetSQLRecoveryMode()
{
     ServerConnection conn = new ServerConnection(dbServer, dbUser, dbPass);

     Server srv = new Server(conn);

     Database db = srv.Databases[dbDatabase];

     var recoveryModel = db.RecoveryModel;

     if (recoveryModel.ToString().Equals("Simple"))
     {
           rbLogBackup.Enabled = false;
           rbCompressedBackup.Enabled = false;
     }
     else
     {
           rbLogBackup.Enabled = true;
           rbCompressedBackup.Enabled = true;
     }
}
```

Comment: Run a query against the server - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189272.aspx#TsqlProcedure

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use SMO - then use this code:

```
Server srv = new Server("yourServerNameHere");

Database db = srv.Databases["YourDatabaseNameHeEre"];

var recoveryModel = db.RecoveryModel;
```

and there you have it!

Answer (score 0):

You can execute this query from you code to get the recovery model.

```
SELECT D.recovery_model_desc FROM sys.databases D WHERE name = 'DataBase_Name'
```

Answer (score 0):

Below query shows the statues of database recovery model on sql server :

```
SELECT name,recovery_model_desc
FROM sys.databases
where name like '%your database name%'
```